# How find this sum of all distinct values of $f(2014)$

Tags: functions

> For all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$, that satisfy
>
> $$f\left(x+\frac1x\right)f\left(x^3+\frac1{x^3}\right) - f\left(x^2+\frac1{x^2}\right)^2 = \left(x-\frac1x\right)^2,$$
>
> find the sum of all distinct values of $f(2014)$.

(2): and Find the possible
value $f(2014)$

My idea: let $$x+\dfrac{1}{x}=t,\Longrightarrow x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3}=\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^3-3\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=t^3-3t$$
so
$$f(t)\cdot f(t^3-3t)-f^2(t^2-2)=t^2-4,|t|\ge 2$$

Then I can't Continue,Thank you

Comment: Oh my goodness. What a problem.

Comment: It is sort of obvious $\pm 2014$ are two possible values. can't find other values yet.

Comment: @achillehui,why? Thank you

Comment: $f(x) = \pm x$ are two solutions for the function equation.

Answer (score 9):

If the question has an answer in the sense the number of distinct values $f(2014)$ is at most countable and the sum can be defined, then the answer is $0$.

This is because if $f(x)$ is a solution of the functional equation, so does $-f(x)$.

Comment: I just want to comment that I think this answer is really beautiful.

Comment: It's Nice! Thank you,+1. Now this problem maybe can find the $f(2014)$ possible value.